# Using Stream Field in WagTail throws an error in block content

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I followed [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html) official tutorial for `WagTail`. Now I want to change my `BlogPage` `body` column from `RichText` to `StreamField` in `models.py`.
I follow [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html) manual to make it works.

I changed `BlogPage` class to look like this

```py
class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog_app.BlogCategory', blank=True)

    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(form_classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])


    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('date'),
            FieldPanel('tags'),
            FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        ], heading="Blog information"),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        StreamFieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]
```

Now I'm able to edit `StreamField` in `Admin` page of `Wegtail`.

I changed content of `base.html` from

`{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

to

`{% include_block page.body %}` to not throwing an error.

Now I'm able to see content of `StreamField` in my post. But because I replaced `{% block content %}` I'm not able to see anything else (like all posts on `blog_index_page.html`).
But because `blog_index_page` is looping `posts` I have to include `{% include_block page.body %}` in base to properly render content of `StramField` and not throwing an error that the block content expected string.

My architecture is same as the tutorial site.

Error message is:

`'richtext' template filter received an invalid value; expected string, got <class 'wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue'>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` line in base.html. This is the base template shared by all page types, so it should only contain things that are meaningful to all page types, like the `<title>` tag - the `{% block content %}` is a placeholder that the individual templates (blog_index_page.html and blog_page.html) will use to insert their own content. See [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) for more explanation.

The correct lines to change are:

- in blog_page.html: `{{ page.body|richtext }}` becomes `{% include_block page.body %}`
- in blog_index_page.html: `{{ post.specific.body|richtext }}` becomes `{% include_block post.specific.body %}`